# Web Developer Vocabulary

Tags: resources, terminology, technology

I'm looking for a list of vocabulary used for developer / programming terminology, with such terms as "Constructors", " Framework", "DI", "CMS" or other similar words.

I found some pages on the IT fields but the terms used are not technical enough (e.g "computer", "screen"...etc).

If someone knows where to find a nice list for development terms, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using 科技英汉大辞典

Comment: I'm not a fan of translating every word in the tech field into Chinese. IMO, CMS is much better than 内容管理系统

Comment: There are many 计算机英语词典,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- access level - 存取權限 (访问级别)
- algorithm - 演算法 (算法)
- array - 陣列（数组）
- array index - 陣列索引 （数组索引）
- async - (异步)
- binary tree - (二叉树)
- build - (构建)
- catch (like try/catch) - (捕获)
- char - 字元 (字符)
- class - 類別 （类）
- class method - 類別方法 (类方法)
- class variable - 類別變數 (类变量)
- compile - (编译)
- construct - 建構 （构造）
- curly bracket - (花括号)
- database - 資料庫/數據庫 (数据库)
- double -  雙精度浮點數（双精度浮点数）
- double quotes- 雙引號 （双引号）
- escaped chars - 跳脫字元（转义字符）
- exception - (异常)
- floating point value - 浮點數（浮点数）
- function - 函數/函式 （函数）
- foreign key - (外键)
- graph - 圖 （图形）
- GUI - 圖形使用者界面 （图形用户界面）
- hardware - 硬體 (硬件)
- loop - 迴圈（循环）
- macro - 巨集 (宏)
- multithreaded [program] - (多线[程])
- object - 物件 （对象）
- ORM (Object Relational Mapping) - (对象关系映射程序)
- parenthesis - (圆括号)
- primary index - (主索引)
- primary key - (主键)
- program - 程式 (程序)
- query - (查询)
- repository - (存储库)
- Row + Column - 行和列 (行和列)
- single quote- 單引號 （单引号）
- software package - 軟體包 (軟件包)
- square bracket - (方括号)
- String - 字串 (字符串)
- table join - (表连接)
- throw (as in throw exception) - (抛出)

Edit: Thanks to feedback in the comments I made a bunch of changes to traditional + simplified. Parenthesis is simplified (PRC) and non parenthesis is traditional (ROC/Taiwan). I removed the ones I'm not sure about so some of them only have one or the other.

Comment: The difference between traditional and simplified Chinese may be more than just converting each character.

Comment: Yeah you're completely right, sorry about that. Made changes.

Comment: I think this answer needs further revision because the distinction between traditional vs simplified characters is different from the distinction between usage in mainland China and in Taiwan. For example, I assume programmers in Hong Kong writing in Mandarin would use traditional characters. Which distinction do you want to make? Both?

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler I assume they're making the mainland/Taiwan distinction, and they're using the character sets that would be most common for those different standards. Agreed that places like HK might not be exactly reflected by either.

Answer (score 5):

- "constructor": "构造函数"
- "framework": "框架"
- "dependency injection": "依赖注入"
- "content management system": "内容管理系统"

Instead of looking for a word table, you can refer to textbooks that cover programming languages (such as C++ or Java) in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

this glossary is quite useful: https://www.ogcio.gov.hk/en/our_work/infrastructure/methodology/glossary/doc/IT_Glossary.pdf

Comment: Please avoid giving link-only answers. You may also explain the relevance of the link to the question.