# Object oriented programming terms class, object, instance, attribute, method

Tags: resources, terminology, technology

Answers to [Web Developer Vocabulary](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/22171/18487) give many useful terms, but I'm working with someone and we need to read further about five specific terms in object oriented programming (e.g. Python or similar).

- class
- object
- instance
- attribute
- method

I know very little Chinese, and a colleague I am working with needs to read further on this topic so we can continue to discuss. Eventually they will need to know how to write these traditional Chinese characters, but for searching for material to read, I think the terms in either traditional or simplified will get us going.

What's important is that they are the expressions that object oriented programmers use when explaining these concepts.

Comment: After posting, I found [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/16418/18487) which links to http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/ which may readily provide answers to my question. I'm not sure if I should delete this question now or leave it for answers to be posted. I don't feel qualified to post an answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: The below answers apply to mainland Mandarin Chinese. For technical vocabulary, the words used in different regions often have differences. The link you posted in your comment looks like it uses Taiwan standards.

- Class 类
- Object 对象
- Instance 实例
- Attribute 属性
- Method 方法

"Object oriented" is 面向对象. You can find more at the [面向对象程序设计 Chinese Wikipedia page](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%9D%A2%E5%90%91%E5%AF%B9%E8%B1%A1%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E8%AE%BE%E8%AE%A1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've had one bit of feedback so far; 物件 might also be used in Taiwan for "object".